# componentWillReceiveProps this.props and nextProps always the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a parent component ProductTest that holds state as the source of truth.  The state is an array of variant items.  Each item is simplified for this example and has a title.

When a Variant's title is updated, the child will call it's handler callback via the prop passed by the parent.  The parent then updates state, and the child will then have a new title property.

What I am seeing is that the child's `componentWillReceiveProps` function will display the same value for `this.props` and `nextProps`.  I would think that since the value is supplied by the parent, the two would be different.

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Here is the parent **ProductTest** component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'
import Variant from './variants/Variant'

import { REACT_APP_API_URL, REACT_APP_SITE_KEY } from '../../../shared/vars'

import '../../../css/variants.css'

class ProductTest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            variants: []
        }

        this.handleVariantTitleChange = this.handleVariantTitleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleVariantValueChange = this.handleVariantValueChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData()
    }

    loadData() {
        const apiEndpoint = 'products/some-product'
        const AUTH_HEADER = { Authorization: REACT_APP_SITE_KEY }
        return axios.get(REACT_APP_API_URL + apiEndpoint, { headers: AUTH_HEADER })
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ variants: response.data.product.variants })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("YA GOOFED BUD!", err)
            })
    }

    handleVariantTitleChange(e, i) {
        let { variants } = this.state
        const { value } = e.target

        variants = variants.map((item, index) => {
            item.title = i === index ? value : item.title
            return item
        })

        this.setState({ variants })
    }

    handleVariantValueChange(e, id) {
        let { variants } = this.state
        const { value } = e.target

        variants = variants.map(variant => {
            variant.items = variant.items.map(item => {
                item.title = id === item.id ? value : item.title
                return item
            })
            return variant
        })

        this.setState({ variants })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.variants.map((variant, i) => {
                    return <Variant key={i}
                        variant={variant}
                        index={i}
                        changeVariantTitle={this.handleVariantTitleChange}
                        changeVariantValue={this.handleVariantValueChange}
                    />
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ProductTest
```

Here is the child **Variant** component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Variant extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log(this.props, nextProps)
    }

    render() {
        const { variant, index } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="variant-wrapper" data-new="new_value">
                <div className="ajax-error" data-hbs-id="{{id}}"></div>
                <div className="varient-item-titles">
                    <div className="variant-item-title">
                        Title
                    </div>
                    <div className="varient-attribute-titles">
                        <div className="variant-attribute">Value</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="variant-item-content">
                    <div className="variant-label">
                        <input type="text" name="variant_label" value={variant.title} placeholder="Size, colour, etc."
                            onChange={e => this.props.changeVariantTitle(e, index)}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Variant
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**Console.log()**

These two objects are this.props and nextProps.  Notice the title property is not different, as I'd expect them to be.

[image]

**SOLUTION!**

The reason for all of those is that I was not correctly altering the parent's state immutably.  I think I was just changing the value at the same memory address, and hence by the time it got to the `componentWillReceiveProps` it was already the new value.  I think...

I found that the following will work:

```
handleVariantTitleChange(e, i){
    const { value } = e.target

    // Immutably clone specific variant item
    let variant = Object.assign({}, this.state.data.variants[i])

    // Set new title to item
    variant.title = value

    // Set the variant to the cloned item
    let variants = this.state.data.variants
    variants[i] = variant

    this.setState({
        data: {
            ...this.state.data,
            variants
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you please share some screenshots of the components before and after you type something on the input boxes.

Comment: Done.  Each of the inputs is a Variant component.  I simply changed the title of the first Variant from 'Colour' to 'Colour1'.
I see one line per Variant in the console as per their `componentWillReceiveProps()` function.  I would expect the two title properties to be different.

Comment: Exactly, the old props also look like the new props because they are passed by reference. I recently learned that the spread operator won't work for 2 dimensional arrays or nested objects. So, if you happen to have such structures you can try deep cloning.

Comment: Yea I thought the spread would work.  No dice.  Live and learn :)